# Intl.DateTimeFormat returns an hour over 24

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following Unix timestamp: `1611328500000` (`Fri Jan 22 2021 10:15:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`).

I need to display it in Korean Standard Time. To do so, I'm using `Intl.DateTimeFormat`. However, for some reason, the result I'm getting is **24:15** when I attempt to format it. Unless I'm delusional, I'm pretty sure that's higher than a 24-hour clock usually goes (0:00 to 23:59).

Google tells me my result should be **0:15**, obviously on the following date (Sat Jan 22).

Here's a minimal working example:

```js
const date = new Date(1611328500000);

const timeOptions = {
  hour12: false,
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit'
};

const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
  timeZone: 'Asia/Seoul', ...timeOptions
});

console.log(formatter.format(date));
```

Am I crazy? Can times go up to 24:15 in some circumstances? What is happening here?

---

**EDIT**: I just found [this page](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/issues/1577) which seems to be experiencing a similar problem. The answer provided there points me towards something called `hourCycle`, with a link to MDN's `Intl.DateTimeFormat`.

However, `hourCycle` only appears once on that page, in the browser support section. Adding the suggested `hourCycle: h11` to my `timeOptions` did not work.

Digging further, I found [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/hourCycle), which lists `h23` as a valid option. Surely this is what I'm after! But, alas... my result is still 24:15.

Comment: I'm seeing `00:15`.

Comment: @StackSlave That's what I was afraid of someone seeing... https://i.imgur.com/vKbpVA8.png here's my result, just so people can know I'm not crazy...

Comment: @matthew-e-brown `24:15` on my end. Curious.

Comment: Firefox shows `00:15`, Chrome shows `24:15`. Chrome bug or Firefox bug?

Comment: [Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1045791) but also affects Node since both use the underlying [V8](https://v8.dev/) JavaScript engine

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Switch from `hour12: true` to `hourCycle: 'h23'` to display the hours from `00:00` to `23:59`.

```js
const date = new Date(1611328500000);

const timeOptions = {
  hourCycle: 'h23',
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit'
};

const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
  timeZone: 'Asia/Seoul', ...timeOptions
});

console.log(formatter.format(date));
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much! I found some data on `hourCycle` but didn't realize it was mutually exclusive with `hour12`. That was the key.

Comment: Note also that the language code (aka "locale") can override both the *hourCycle* and *hour12* options depending on other option values.

Answer (score 1):

I used the below code and it worked to transform the input `3000000` milliseconds  to the output `00:50:00.000Z`

```js
const dateInMilliseconds = 3000000
const formatterConfig = { 
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric",
  hourCycle: "h23",
  timeZone: "UTC",
  fractionalSecondDigits: 3
}
const dateInFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], formatterConfig).format(dateInMilliseconds)+'Z';
// 00:50:00.000Z
```