# Show time as 0:30:00 instead of 24:30:00 for English

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have the following code to format dates with time. For some reason the English strings show times  as `24:30:00` while the German one shows `00:30:00`

Is there any way to make the English ones show `00:30:00` as well.

```js
const options = {
  year: "numeric",
  month: "numeric",
  day: "numeric",
  hour12: false,
  timeZone: "UTC",
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric",
} as Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions;

Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-En", options).format(new Date(1800000)); // '1/1/1970, 24:30:00'
Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-Au", options).format(new Date(1800000)); // '01/01/1970, 24:30:00'
Intl.DateTimeFormat("de-De", options).format(new Date(1800000)); // '1.1.1970, 00:30:00'
```

Comment: "For some reason the English strings show"... well, isn't that just [how the English do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00)? If you want to use i18n then this is the kind of stuff that you don't want to mess with; it's exactly why we rely on the libraries and API's that take care of this for us.

Comment: must be a browser specific problem

Comment: @robiii we have english people complain about it so it seems not so obvious. And I would be also fine with not solving it.

Comment: indeed it is a browser specific problem ... oh Chrome, why do you get EVERYTHING wrong

Comment: What environment is this? I tried your code in the Firefox console and it output "1/1/1970, 00:30:00" as I would expect.

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604554/intl-datetimeformat-returns-an-hour-over-24, you can use `hourCycle: 'h23'` to get rid of the hour greater than 24

Comment: @xubeiyan - don't forget to remove the `hour12` config :p

Comment: The rules for *toLocaleString* formatting are based on data in the [*CLDR Project*](https://cldr.unicode.org/translation/date-time/date-time-patterns). The format returned for a particular language is what is considered the most common format, it may not be the one that particular individuals who speak that language actually use or want to see. Frankly, I think that most of the Intl.DateTimeFormat API is a waste of time, the only good bits are *formatToParts* (which returns the parts so you can format them yourself) and the timezone and calendar 
options.

Comment: Also see [*Javascript Date() returns hour over 24*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604554/intl-datetimeformat-returns-an-hour-over-24), which shows that the hour cycle option is buggy in some implementations.